# Regular Expression to Modify Title on Autoblogged Plugin

Tags: regex, xml-parsing, autoblogged

I need to get rid of some words from every feed title.
Example:
titles:

```
Vans model 10 . 390 From Random Data
Nike model 982 . Errant From Default Data
Timberland old school From Whatever
```

Now, I need always to remove everything after "From"

The result should be:

```
Vans model 10 . 390
Nike model 982 . Errant
Timberland old school
```

I cannot use Search/Replace fields because same data is present in %content%, the only solutions is custom fields title regex but i dont know how.

Comment: This sounds like a job for XPath, not regex.

Comment: Try this `(.+)from` regex. demo https://regex101.com/r/dV4pB5/1

Comment: Using the autoblogged plugin custom fields i have set as 'Custom Field' = title and 'Custom Field Value' = %regex("%title%", "(.+)(From|Alternative)", "1")% Myowntextafterregexedtitle.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use search/replace, then you can use regex lookahead to capture the content you want like this:

```
(.+?)(?=\sFrom)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK4uO9/2)**

However, in case you could use search/replace you could use this regex:

```
From.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK4uO9/3)**